# How can I send a notification to a particular user when there is a change in cloud firestore?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications, cloud, messaging

I am creating a carpool application. When the ride is accepted/rejected, I want the user on other-end to receive a notification. All of this needs to be done by the onPressed() of driver side. P.s:- I have manually sent notifications to eligible users through cloud messaging. I am stuck here!

Comment: you would have to use cloud functions to listen to that particular change and notify the user through fcm messaging

Comment: another way is to make both users listen to firebase rtdb for changes. You would have to make both of them have their app opened the whole time and  both reference to the same database. That would be a more inefficient way to do it but its easier

Comment: I have already done the second way. I want to use the cloud functions, but I am confused with them.